# API is showing empty value if i click search button for the second time in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api

am working on angular.
Am working for front end and integrating the API for post method in search criteria, everything works fine except this .
When i click the search button for first time i get the data in the table as per the requirement, but if i click  the button for second time without the page refresh the data is showing the empty value and showing no results found.

This is my function i'm using :

```
  $scope.generate = function() {
  $scope.searchResults = false
  $scope.showLoader = true
  reportService.search($scope.query).success(function(data) {
    $scope.query = data
    console.log(data);
    $scope.showLoader = false
    setTimeout(function() {
      //window.scroll(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
      }, 'slow');
    }, 200);
    $scope.results = data
    if ($scope.results.length > 0) {
      $scope.searchResults = true
      _.forEach($scope.results.entities, function(obj) {
        console.log("hi");
        obj.isChecked = false;
      });
      console.log("hi1");
      $scope.view_data = $scope.results.slice($scope.skip, $scope.items + $scope.skip);

      $scope.totalItems = $scope.results.length;
      console.log(data);

      $scope.results = data;


    } else {
      $scope.searchResults = false
      notificationFactory.warning('No results Found')
      $scope.showLoader = false
    }

  }).error(function(data) {
    notificationFactory.warning('Error Searching Reports')
    console.log(data);
  })


}
```

I am a new bee to angular , so can anyone please help me from this 
It would be very helpful if someone helps me with this, please.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `reportService.search($scope.query)` you use `$scope.query` but then you overwrite this variable immediately by `$scope.query = data;`.

Additionally, not related with the question. Do not use jQuery-like operation in angular:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  //window.scroll(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 'slow');
}, 200);
```

this operation you could achieve by angular animations https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations